# How we can order exact match on top in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching keyword from all the content. If I am entering complete Post Title in search box it is displaying in bottom. As I am order my post according to `post_date` but is there any way
so that most score will be display on top and I can combine this order based on `post_date` and `exact match`.

I am using below query :-

```
    {
       "query": {
          "bool": {
             "must": [
                {
                   "query_string": {
                      "query": "Post title keyword goes here.."
                   }
                },
                {
                   "term": {
                      "post_status": "publish"
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       },
       "sort": [
          {
             "post_date": {
                "order": "desc"
             }
          }
       ],
       "from": 0,
       "size": 20
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can order exact match on top using `_score` in [sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html). I need to change in my JSON like this :-

```
   "sort": [
      "_score",
      {
         "post_date": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ],
```

Add `_score` as a first fields.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that would be grouping which elastic search doesn't support. You can however manipulate scoring and then sort results based on the scoring. More details on how scoring can be changed is available here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Answer (score 0):

i beleve tis is about what you are looking for:

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_filters_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "Post title keyword goes here.."
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "post_status": "publish"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filters": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "post_date"
            }
          },
          "script": "doc['post_date'].date.getMillis() " /* calculate custom boost from date */ 
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "Post title keyword goes here..",
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            }
          },
          "boost": 100
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you do like Roopendra suggested you could drop the nasty post_date filter

Comment: Thanks I am trying to your solution but result almost same, I think boost is good suggestion for content relevance.