# Elasticsearch: how to group searchterms for more relevance in bool query

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a good working searchquery, it searches on "fiets", "reparatie" and both words combined.
Results with both words should rank highest, but now the highest results are either docs with a lot of rudy or a lot of test....

I understand why but I can't figure out how to fix this or find similar queries/issues.
Somehow I should group these blocks but I can't find a syntax that elasticsearch understands.

Also note this is a generated query and the amount of search words can differ. (probably not the most efficient query because I'm new to elasticsearch)

```
{
    "from" : 0, 
    "size" : 10,
    "query" : 
    {
        "bool" : 
        {
            "should" : 
            [
                {"term" : { "beschrijving" : "fiets" }}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving_lang" : "fiets" }}, 
                {"term" : { "titel" : "fiets" }}, 
                {"multi_match" : { "query" : "fiets", "fields" : [ "naam", "rubriek", "subrubriek","keywords","zoekkeywords" ]}},

                {"term" : { "beschrijving" : "reparatie" }}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving_lang" : "reparatie" }}, 
                {"term" : { "titel" : "reparatie" }}, 
                {"multi_match" : { "query" : "reparatie", "fields" : [ "naam", "rubriek", "subrubriek","keywords","zoekkeywords" ]}},

                {"term" : { "beschrijving" : "fietsreparatie" }}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving_lang" : "fietsreparatie" }}, 
                {"term" : { "titel" : "fietsreparatie" }}, 
                {"multi_match" : { "query" : "fietsreparatie", "fields" : [ "naam", "rubriek", "subrubriek","keywords","zoekkeywords" ]}},

                {"term" : { "type" : "3000" }}
            ],
            "must" : 
            [
                {"term" : { "actief" : "1" }}
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match" : 1
        } 
    },
    "facets" : 
    { 
        "rubriek" : { "terms" : { "field" : "rubriek", "size" : 50 } }, 
        "plaats" : { "terms" : { "field" : "plaats", "size" : 50 } } , 
        "provincie" : { "terms" : { "field" : "provincie", "size" : 50 } } , 
        "gemeente" : { "terms" : { "field" : "gemeente", "size" : 50 } } , 
        "subrubriek" : { "terms" : { "field" : "subrubriek", "size" : 50 } } 
    }
}
```

Using multi_match improved thing a little, because the amount of matches of the same keyword is reduced without losing results

```
{
    "from" : 0, 
    "size" : 10,
    "query" : 
    {
        "bool" : 
        {
            "should" : 
            [
                {"match" : {"naam" : {"query" : "test","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving" : "test" }}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving_lang" : "test" }}, 
                {"term" : { "titel" : "test" }}, 
                {"match" : {"rubriek" : {"query" : "test","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"match" : {"subrubriek" : {"query" : "test","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"match" : {"keywords" : {"query" : "test","operator" : "and"} }}, 
                {"match" : {"zoekkeywords" : {"query" : "test","operator" : "and"} }}, 

                {"match" : {"naam" : {"query" : "rudy","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving" : "rudy" }}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving_lang" : "rudy" }}, 
                {"term" : { "titel" : "rudy" }}, 
                {"match" : {"rubriek" : {"query" : "rudy","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"match" : {"subrubriek" : {"query" : "rudy","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"match" : {"keywords" : {"query" : "rudy","operator" : "and"} }}, 
                {"match" : {"zoekkeywords" : {"query" : "rudy","operator" : "and"} }}, 

                {"match" : {"naam" : {"query" : "testrudy","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving" : "testrudy" }}, 
                {"term" : { "beschrijving_lang" : "testrudy" }}, 
                {"term" : { "titel" : "testrudy" }}, 
                {"match" : {"rubriek" : 
                {"query" : "testrudy","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"match" : {"subrubriek" : {"query" : "testrudy","operator" : "and"}}}, 
                {"match" : {"keywords" : {"query" : "testrudy","operator" : "and"} }}, 
                {"match" : {"zoekkeywords" : {"query" : "testrudy","operator" : "and"} }}, 

                {"term" : { "type" : "3000" }}
            ],
            "must" : 
            [
                {"term" : { "actief" : "1" }}
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match" : 1
        } 
    },
    "facets" : 
    { 
        "rubriek" : { "terms" : { "field" : "rubriek", "size" : 50 } }, 
        "plaats" : { "terms" : { "field" : "plaats", "size" : 50 } } , 
        "provincie" : { "terms" : { "field" : "provincie", "size" : 50 } } , 
        "gemeente" : { "terms" : { "field" : "gemeente", "size" : 50 } } , 
        "subrubriek" : { "terms" : { "field" : "subrubriek", "size" : 50 } } 
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need more relevant result on top ? Can you more elaborate ?

Comment: Yes the amount of results are ok, but results containing both words should be on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-arranging your query to follow this pattern:

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               { "multi_match": {
                   "query":  "fiets",
                   "fields": [ "beschrijving", "beschrijving_lang", "titel" ]
               }},
               { "multi_match": {
                   "query":  "reparatie",
                   "fields": [ "beschrijving", "beschrijving_lang", "titel" ]
               }},
               { "multi_match": {
                   "query":  "something_else",
                   "fields": [ "beschrijving", "beschrijving_lang", "titel" ]
               }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Just a quick example, but it shows the overall layout. The idea is that we want the query to be "word-centric".  We want higher scores for documents that match more of our words.  The `bool` naturally scores documents higher that satisfy more `should` clauses.  Since the clauses in the `should` are searching for single terms we can guarantee that more words == higher score.

You could even add a `minimum_should_match` clause to the `bool` and mandate that 2/3 clauses must match, etc.

By using a `multi_match` query for each word, we can look across many fields and don't care where the term appears.

This is just a general pattern and you can extend and modify it, but this should get you started.

*Credit goes to Clinton Gormley for this query pattern*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_score` it will sort your result based on match `score`. Your query will be look like this:-

```
{
    "from" : 0, 
    "size" : 10,
    "query" : 
    {
    "bool" : 
    {
        "should" : 
        [
    ...........
    .......
    } 
    },
    "facets" : 
    { 
    .....
    },
     "sort": [
      "_score"
   ]
}
```

[reference link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't change the order, could this sort be the default sorting?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324264/how-we-can-order-exact-match-on-top-in-elasticsearch it may help you

Comment: thanks tried some new stuff, but didn't work out. and sadly i cant assist with you're problem because its more complex